# find $\lim_{n \to \infty }n(b_{n}-a_{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$  and $(b_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ sequences defined by
$$
a_{n} := \sum_{k=1}^{n}\; f\Big(\frac{k-1}{n}\Big)\int\limits_{(k-1)/{n}}^{{k}/{n}}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
\quad  \text{and}\quad
b_{n} := \sum_{k=1}^{n}\; f\Big(\frac{k}{n}\Big)\int\limits_{(k-1)/{n}}^{{k}/{n}}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.
$$
Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty }(b_{n}-a_{n})=0$ and find $\lim_{n \to \infty }n(b_{n}-a_{n})$

Comment: After realizing this is two different Riemann sums for the same integral, what did you try?

Comment: That looks like a Riemann-Stieltjes integral...which, btw, reduces to a Riemann integral.

Comment: Why the stream of questions with zero context? Did you miss every howtoask page on the site?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\;f\;$ continuous on $\;[0,1]\;$ , there exists a primitive function $\;F\;$ for it on this interval, so

$$b_n-a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(f\left(\frac kn\right)-f\left(\frac{k-1}n\right)\right)\int_{\frac{k-1}n}^{\frac kn}f(t)\,dt=$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(f\left(\frac kn\right)-f\left(\frac{k-1}n\right)\right)\left(F\left(\frac kn\right)-F\left(\frac{k-1}n\right)\right)=$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(f\left(\frac kn\right)-f\left(\frac{k-1}n\right)\right)\frac{F'(c_n)}n\;,\;\;c_n\in\left(\frac{k-1}n,\,\frac kn\right)=$$

$$=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(f\left(\frac kn\right)-f\left(\frac{k-1}n\right)\right)F'(c_n)\;(**)$$

But the last sum's limit is the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\;\int\limits_0^1F'(x)df(x)=\int_0^1f(x)df(x)\;$ , which exists if $\;f\;$ is of bounded variation in $\;[0,1]\;$ , and at any case it is a bounded quantity, so taking the limit when $\;n\to\infty\;$ in (**) we get zero , and thus

$$n(b_n-a_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\int_0^1f(x)df(x)=\text{ The R.S. integral of $\;f\;$ wrt itself}$$

If the integral above exists, then integrating by parts we get:

$$\int_0^1f(x)df(x)=f(1)^2-f(0)^2-\int_0^1f(x)df(x)\implies \int_0^2f(x)df(x)=\frac{f(1)^2-f(0)^2}2$$

Check the above as I can't justify the existence of the R.S. integral without having some more info on $\;f\;$, like being of bounded variation, or monotonous (which would imply b.v., of course), etc.